# Create cookies on other domains via javascript

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

I'm working on a project where I need to create a cookie in another domain of my application, I know that doing it directly is not possible because that would be a security flaw.

```
Example scenario:
Frontend: epictv.cf
Streaming Backend: ipv4-epictv001.infra-imm.epictv.cf

Reason: I need a <video> tag to be pre-authenticated in the streaming domain, since you can't pass any type of header in the tag.
```

For that I thought of making the frontend make a request to the backend and pass in the "body" of this request (GET) the value of the cookie I want to create, but for some reason when axios makes this request the cookie is not created, in however, if i open the route manually works fine!

How could I get the frontend to place a cookie on the backend?

My attempt code:

```
async createCookie(req, res){
const session = req.params.session;
res.cookie("sessao", session, { maxAge: 1000000 });
res.status(200).json({
    "status": "ok"
});
},
```

PS: I know that in the video tag I could pass the url with the authentication in the src itself, but I would rather not do it.